# I can't use a particular list function inside class but without class it works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Doors:
    def start(self):
        print("you stuck at a room")
        print("you see a lever and a bell")
        command = input("What you're gonna do?")
        ans = command.split(" ")
        if ans in ["bell", "call"]:
            print("great job")
        elif "help" in ans or "hint" in ans:
            print("something helpful")
p = Doors()
p.start()
```

the first one(if statement) is not working. but the second one(elif statement) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because in the first (if statement) you are comparing `ans` (which is a list) to another list using `in`.

This should fix it (assuming you have a single word input) -

```
class Doors:
    def start(self):
        print("you stuck at a room")
        print("you see a lever and a bell")
        command = input("What you're gonna do?")
        ans = command.split(" ")
        if ans[0] in ["bell", "call"]:  #This step is the fix, ans[0]
            print("great job")
        elif "help" in ans or "hint" in ans:
            print("something helpful")
p = Doors()
p.start()
```

```
#Input - 'bell'

#Output - 
you stuck at a room
you see a lever and a bell
What you're gonna do?bell
great job
```

---

EDIT: I tried running your code without the class and it fails (not sure how you are able to run it) I would recommend restarting your kernel in case you are using jupyter or clearing the cache of defined functions and variables.

```
def start():
    print("you stuck at a room")
    print("you see a lever and a bell")
    command = input("What you're gonna do?")
    ans = command.split(" ")
    if ans in ["bell", "call"]:  #This step is the fix, ans[0]
        print("great job")
    elif "help" in ans or "hint" in ans:
        print("something helpful")

start()
```

```
you stuck at a room
you see a lever and a bell
What you're gonna do?bell
```

No output when I enter 'bell'

Comment: Please check my updated answer. your bug is not reproducible at my end. I still get no output when I run the function separately. I would recommend restarting the python instance or restarting the kernel if you are using jupyter